# Second request is not working in dojo.io.iframe.send in dojo 1.7

Tags: dojo, websphere-portal, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am uploading a file using dojo.io.iframe.send ajax call using below code. 
Am using dojo 1.7 and WebSphere Portal Server 8.0

```
   dojo.io.iframe.send({
    form: "workReqIDFormWBS",
    handleAs: "text/html",          
    url:"<portlet:actionURL/>",
    load: function(response, ioArgs) {  
    console.log(response, ioArgs);
    return response;
    },error:  function(response, ioArgs) {
        console.log(response, ioArgs);
        return response;
    }

});
```

When am uploding the file for the first time it's working fine,where as from second time onwards nothing is happening. Any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Action URLs are only valid to be invoked once by default. Portal protects against form submission replay incidents by internally assigning an ID within the action URL produced.

You should also be seeing some logging on those subsequent action url requests: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21613334

I suggest either using resource URL and `serveResource()` in your portlet or ensuring that your response from the render phase following the action URL processing regenerate the Action URL value and update a variable your posted javascript reads and uses in subsequent `send()` calls.